# dynamically give name attribute of textbox a value

Tags: php, html

It seems that I can't find a solution to my problem. I tried searching for it but the results given to me contain javascript in the solution. What I would want is to only use PHP.
So my problem is giving dynamically generated textboxes unique names so that I can retrieve their values later on.

Here's my code:

```
<form name="zodiac_quiz" id="zodiac_quiz" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
        <h3>True or False</h3>
        <?php
           for($i=0; $i<count($typeTF); $i++)
           {
               echo "<input type = 'text' size = 12 maxlength = 5 name = TF$i+1 />";
           }
        ?>
        <input type='submit' name='checkAns' id='checkAns' value='Submit Answers'/>
        <br/>

</form>
```

When I test the code to see if it worked using `var_dump()` I only get `NULL`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the generated html correct? I think you will need to correct the html output. not the name generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far easier to use `arrays` (and you're missing lots of quotes in the `input` tag):

```
foreach($typeTF as $t)
{
    echo '<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="5" name="TF[]" />';
}
```

Then just loop through `$_POST['TF']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do math functions inside an echo string you have two options:

```
echo "<input type = 'text' size = 12 maxlength = 5 name = 'TF" . $i+1 . "' />";
```

Or you can do a temp variable

```
$temp = $i + 1;
echo "<input type = 'text' size = 12 maxlength = 5 name = '$temp' />";
```

But I would do it as an array:

```
echo "<input type = 'text' size = 12 maxlength = 5 name = 'TF[" . $i+1 . "]' />";
```

So you can access all values in the `$_POST['TF']` array.